# Merge Ruby arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge

I have a few arrays of Ruby objects of class `UserInfo`:

```
class UserInfo  
    attr_accessor :name, :title, :age
end
```

How can I merge these arrays into one array? A user is identified by its name, so I want no duplicate names. If name, title, age, etc. are equal I'd like to have 1 entry in the new array. If names are the same, but any of the other details differ I probably want those 2 users in a different array to manually fix the errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You use the verb merging, when you really mean removing duplicates. Also you have tagged this with `hash` when you are asking about arrays. You should probably edit this question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Olly: changed tag from 'hash' to 'arrays'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year ago [I monkey patched](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2009/11/02/comparing-instance-variables-in-ruby) a kind of cryptic `instance_variables_compare` on `Object`. I guess you could use that.

```
class Object
  def instance_variables_compare(o)
    Hash[*self.instance_variables.map {|v|
      self.instance_variable_get(v)!=o.instance_variable_get(v) ? 
      [v,o.instance_variable_get(v)] : []}.flatten]
  end
end
```

**A cheesy example**

```
require 'Date'

class Cheese
  attr_accessor :name, :weight, :expire_date
  def initialize(name, weight, expire_date)
    @name, @weight, @expire_date = name, weight, expire_date
  end
end

stilton=Cheese.new('Stilton', 250, Date.parse("2010-12-02"))
gorgonzola=Cheese.new('Gorgonzola', 250, Date.parse("2010-12-17"))
```

**irb is my weapon of choice**

```
>> stilton.instance_variables_compare(gorgonzola)
=> {"@name"=>"Gorgonzola", "@expire_date"=>#<Date: 4910305/2,0,2299161>}
>> gorgonzola.instance_variables_compare(stilton)
=> {"@name"=>"Stilton", "@expire_date"=>#<Date: 4910275/2,0,2299161>}
>> stilton.expire_date=gorgonzola.expire_date
=> #<Date: 4910305/2,0,2299161>
>> stilton.instance_variables_compare(gorgonzola)
=> {"@name"=>"Gorgonzola"}
>> stilton.instance_variables_compare(stilton)
=> {}
```

As you can see the `instance_variables_compare` returns an empty Hash if the two objects has the same content.

**An array of cheese**

```
stilton2=Cheese.new('Stilton', 210, Date.parse("2010-12-02"))
gorgonzola2=Cheese.new('Gorgonzola', 250, Date.parse("2010-12-17"))

arr=[]<<stilton<<stilton2<<gorgonzola<<gorgonzola2
```

**One hash without problems and one with**

```
h={}
problems=Hash.new([])

arr.each {|c| 
  if h.has_key?(c.name)
    if problems.has_key?(c.name)
      problems[c.name]=problems[c.name]<<c
    elsif h[c.name].instance_variables_compare(c) != {}
      problems[c.name]=problems[c.name]<<c<<h[c.name]
      h.delete(c.name)
    end
  else 
    h[c.name]=c
  end
}
```

Now the Hash `h` contains the objects without merging problems and the `problems` hash contains those that has instance variables that differs.

```
>> h
=> {"Gorgonzola"=>#<Cheese:0xb375e8 @name="Gorgonzola", @weight=250, @expire_date=#<Date: 2010-12-17 (4911095/2,0,2299161)>>}

>> problems
=> {"Stilton"=>[#<Cheese:0xf54c30 @name="Stilton", @weight=210, @expire_date=#<Date: 2010-12-02 (4911065/2,0,2299161)>>, #<Cheese:0xfdeca8 @name="Stilton", @weight=250,@expire_date=#<Date: 2010-12-02 (4911065/2,0,2299161)>>]}
```

As far as I can see you will not have to modify this code at all to support an array of `UserInfo` objects.

It would most probably be much faster to compare the properties directly or with a override of `==`. This is how you override `==`

```
def ==(other)
  return self.weight == other.weight && self.expire_date == other.expire_date
end
```

and the loop changes into this

```
arr.each {|c| 
  if h.has_key?(c.name)
    if problems.has_key?(c.name)
      problems[c.name]=problems[c.name]<<c
    elsif h[c.name] != c
      problems[c.name]=problems[c.name]<<c<<h[c.name]
      h.delete(c.name)
    end
  else 
    h[c.name]=c
  end
}
```

Finally you might want to convert the `Hash` back to an `Array`

```
result = h.values
```

Comment: It's mostly copy and paste from an old blog post. Also I just corrected a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine equality comparison on your object, and you can get rid of actual duplicates quickly with [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000747)

```
class UserInfo
  attr_accessor :name, :title, :age

  def == other
    name==other.name and title==other.title and age==other.age
  end
end

# assuming a and b are arrays of UserInfo objects
c = a | b
# c will only contain one of each UserInfo
```

Then you can sort by name and look for name-only duplicates

```
d = c.sort{ |p,q| p.name <=> q.name } #sort by name
name = ""
e = []
d.each do |item|
  if item.name == name
    e[-1] = [e[-1],item].flatten 
  else
    e << item
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another potential way. If you have a way of identifying each UserInfo, say a to_str method that prints out the values:

```
  def to_str()
    return "#{@name}:#{@title}:#{@age}"
  end
```

You can use inject and a hash

```
all_users = a + b # collection of users to "merge"    
res = all_users.inject({})do |h,v|
  h[v.to_str] = v  #save the value indexed on the string output
  h # return h for the next iteration
end

merged = res.values #the unique users
```